Error With Permissions to write to file but file is in project dir
(INFO)
OS: Windows
wars.py already exists
I do not know how to check the permissions of the current working directory. But when i use vscode to run it it doesnt give me the error but doesn't update the file
I was creating a program to transfer user inputs over discord to do this you needed 2 discord bots so i made a setup file for the tokens this setup file works fine it opens a tk window in which it asked for the data but then it would give me permission error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'vars.py' here is my code i am confused in the past when writing to files (in replit) i didnt encounter any permision error's.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox



def write_to_file(file_path, text):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(text)


def submit():
    vc_id = vc_id_entry.get()
    sender_token = sender_token_entry.get()
    receiver_token = receiver_token_entry.get()
    write_to_file("vars.py", f"vc_id = {vc_id}\ns_token = \"{sender_token}\"\nr_token = \"{receiver_token}\"\nsetup = True")
    messagebox.showinfo("Setup Done", "You may now close the window")


# Create main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Setup")

# Create labels and entry boxes
vc_id_label = ttk.Label(root, text="VC ID:")
vc_id_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)

vc_id_entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
vc_id_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

sender_token_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Sender Token:")
sender_token_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)

sender_token_entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
sender_token_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

receiver_token_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Receiver Token:")
receiver_token_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)

receiver_token_entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
receiver_token_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

# Submit button
submit_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit)
submit_button.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, pady=10)

# Start GUI
root.mainloop()


I tryed to fix it by using chatgpt but it just gave me a ton of bs. I was expecting it to run and fill in the variables it asked for into the vars.py file which would be accsesed by the main file to run the discord bots.

This problem isn't with tkinter. It's saying that python doesn't have permissions to write to that file. What OS are you using? Does vars.py already exist? What are it's/the current working directory's permissions?

Remember that it doesn't write to the directory that contains the script.  It writes to the CURRENT directory.  You might do print(os.getcwd()) so you know what that is.

I awnsered all of your questions @TheLizzard

That Explains Something, I'm not sure what but i am pretty sure it's a issue. It returns 'C:\Windows\system32' I am still confused should i specify th efull directory somehow?

You can add os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)). That will change the current working directory to the one where the python file is. Alternatively you can use the full path to vars.py.

maybe use tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename to select destination file.

@TheLizzard Thank you so much that worked, the one with the os.chdir. This is probaly the best experince ive had with stack overflow in a while. Do you know if this works on other operating systems?

@Suberbmuffin os.chdir works on all OSes.
